# Anyone can provide uploadprogress.dll extension for php 5.3.0?

Tags: php, php-extension

I need uploadprogress extension for php on windows. I downloaded dlls from [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/), but the version doesn't match with my php. I have php 5.3.0 build 20090626 VC++6. And I couldn't find a compatible uploadprogress.dll.
I can't build it because I don't have php source of my version.
Also I don't want to use APC extension. can anyone provide this dll for me?

Comment: "I can't build it because I don't have php source of my version" - this can be fixed: http://www.php.net/releases/ and phpinfo() can tell you which configuration options have been used to build your version of php.

Comment: @VolkerK Thank you for the link! I'm downloading it. I had PHP source version 5.3.3 and I couldn't build under windows using VStudio 2008 ( about 5004 errors:D ). maybe this one help me.

Comment: You can ask Pierre to build it. I don't have VC6... Only VC9 and VC10. Is there any reason you're using VC6? The builds with the recent versions of the compiler are faster.

Comment: @Artefacto actually I am using wamp and I have no time to configure all my developing environment and settings again. and also apache2 doesn't work with php compiled with VC9.

Comment: @Mor It does if you use a version compiled with VC9 like the one from apache lounge. You don't need to configure anything (`httpd.conf`/`php.ini`) you just have to replace the binaries.

Comment: @Artefacto I'm trying to build it using VC9 but it is too hard for me. nmake command have so many problems and errors here! may I ask you to build the extension with VC9 for me? am using this tutorial: http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: @Mor http://nebm.ist.utl.pt/~glopes/misc/php_uploadprogress.dll (VC9, Thread safety, release, x86)

Comment: @Artefacto thank you for the DLL. everything is ok except that I'm running php compiled with VC6. I will change php. can you let me know how you compiled it? am working on it about 3 hours without success!!

Comment: @Mor Well, it's just a matter of following the instructions. There's also #php-dev-win@Freenode

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is two solution for this problem. One is to build extension yourself with php and VC6. it is not recommended because there would be lots of bugs and errors. the second solution is to upgrade apache to apache lounge ( it is built with VC9 ) and then use php VC9 and uploadprogress.dll provided by [pierre](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) or [Artefacto](http://nebm.ist.utl.pt/~glopes/misc/php_uploadprogress.dll) or build it with VC9.

Comment: There will be lots of bugs and errors? Only if you don't follow the instructions Pierre's provided in the wiki...

Comment: Yes! I followed the instructions and finally I left with lots of bugs and errors. maybe I'm not professional, anyway, the other way is much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the JavaScript APIs for upload progress? They're much more accurate and allow you to report progress without a server callback.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest#Monitoring_progress

It should be noted that the uploads occur via AJAX in this instance, which may or may not be helpful. AJAX-based uploads can be cancelled, restarted, or otherwise interacted with using JS alone.

The downside is that it's a tad complicated to bundle the data. Some user agents still have issues with binary strings, so it may be necessary to convert the data to base 64 before uploading it. Also, it should be assumed that not all user agents support this feature.

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: actually I don't need to see progress!! I want the content of uploaded file even if it is not completely uploaded. This extension has this feature so I want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a VC6 built dll that will work with Wamp2 and php5.3 I found one here: http://www.xs4all.nl/~lupro/zooi/uploadprogress/php_uploadprogress-1.0.1-5.3-Win32-VC6-x86.zip
which seems to work for me. Please note that I didn't build this, only stumbled on it after much searching