# php_uploadprogress.dll on Xampp for windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I'm trying to setup the pecl uploadprogress extension on my localhost development computer.  It's a windows 7 home premium machine with XAMPP 1.7.3.

I've followed many guides on setting it up on windows machines but I've ran into a problem that I had setting it up on our CentOS webserver.  After making and installing the extension it refused to start with

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: uploadprogress: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

I fixed this by using yum to retrieve the correct perl package, installed it, copied the uploadprogress.os into the correct folder and got that working.

When I checked the apache error.log on my localhost I see the very same message with the same API codes.  So I assume that considering my development machine and live server have the same version of PHP that php_uploadprogress-1.0.0-5.2-Win32-VC6-x86 was created for PHP 5.2.
Where can I get my hands on the dll for php 5.3??

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489545/anyone-can-provide-uploadprogress-dll-extension-for-php-5-3-0